# DOWNLOAD CHROMIUM FAILED

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

please help me ..
after i run the command on cmd windows:

> > autoninja -C out\Default chrome

i get this error :

---

PLEASE ATTACH THE FOLLOWING FILES TO THE BUG REPORT:
Preprocessed source(s) and associated run script(s) are located at:
clang-cl: note: diagnostic msg: ../../tools/clang/crashreports\webstore_reinstaller-5597f5.sh
clang-cl: note: diagnostic msg:

---

[33302/47964] CXX obj/chro...ions/extension_updater.obj
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

what does it mean ? and what do i do ?
thanks

Comment: why is this under they python tag?

Answer (score 0):

PLEASE ATTACH THE FOLLOWING FILES TO THE BUG REPORT:
Preprocessed source(s) and associated run script(s) are located at:
clang-cl: note: diagnostic msg: ../../tools/clang/crashreports\report_uploader-0b2833.sh
clang-cl: note: diagnostic msg:

---

ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
metric                  count   avg (us)        total (ms)
.ninja parse            6068    22503.4         136550.4
canonicalize str        2514329 0.0             57.1
canonicalize path       4487911 0.0             66.5
lookup node             4267195 2.2             9345.5
.ninja_log load         1       142334.0        142.3
.ninja_deps load        1       784797.0        784.8
node stat               242683  95.2            23098.3
depfile load            221     169.6           37.5
StartEdge               22865   13651.8         312148.5
FinishCommand           22865   61902.5         1415401.4
CLParser::Parse         11641   1168.6          13603.8

path->node hash load 0.88 (231961 entries / 262144 buckets)

this error is after i run with :

> > autoninja -C out\Default base